# Accumulating total at every iteration of a button press

Tags: c#

I'm trying to multiply the values in my quantity and price textboxs and then pass that into a total textbox that will update every time the add button is pressed. Following is what I've tried so far.

How do I make it show the product in my total text box and accumulate it? E.g. At quantity 4 and price 4 it reads 16 then if I put in a quantity 2 and price 2 it will read 20.

```
private void add_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (customer_textBox.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Please enter valid Customer");
            }
            if (quantity_textBox.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Please enter valid Quantity");
            }
            if (price_per_item_textBox.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                    "Please enter valid Price");
            }
            else
            {
                decimal total = Decimal.Parse(total_textBox.Text);
                total = int.Parse(quantity_textBox.Text) * int.Parse(price_per_item_textBox.Text);
                total += total;
                total_textBox.Text = total.ToString();
            }
            quantity_textBox.Clear();
            customer_textBox.Clear();
            price_per_item_textBox.Clear();
            item_textBox.Clear();
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {

        }
        total_textBox.Focus();


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
decimal total = Decimal.Parse(total_textBox.Text);
total = int.Parse(quantity_textBox.Text) * int.Parse(price_per_item_textBox.Text);
total += total;
total_textBox.Text = total.ToString();
```

to this

```
total = currentTotal + (decimal.Parse(quantity_textBox.Text) * decimal.Parse(price_per_item_textBox.Text));
total_textBox.Text = total.ToString("C");
```

and create a class-level variable `private decimal currentTotal;`

The first line isn't needed as you just re-assign the value of the text box in the fourth line. I am assuming price per item is a `decimal` value (eg. $1.99). Parsing it as an `int` will lose the precision (eg. $1.99 will become 1). Multiplying an `int` by an `int` will also return an `int`, $1.99 * 2 will become 1 * 2 which will be simply 2 instead of $3.98.